# Keras model with RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: keras, gridsearchcv

Im learning deep learn with keras and I have problem with RandomizedSearchCV.

I receive error when I use param_distribs like below.

```
keras_reg = scikeras.wrappers.KerasRegressor(build_model)
keras_reg.fit(
    X_train,y_train,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data = [X_valid, y_valid],
    callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)]
)
mse_test = keras_reg.score(X_test,y_test)
X_new = X_test[:3]
y_pred = keras_reg.predict(X_new)

#Przeszukiwanie siatki

param_distribs = {
    "n_hidden": [0, 1, 2, 3],
    "n_neurons": np.arange(1, 100)
}

rnd_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_reg, param_distributions=param_distribs, n_iter=10, cv=3, verbose=2)
rnd_search_cv.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=100,
                  validation_data = (X_valid,y_valid),
                  callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])


print(rnd_search_cv.best_params_)
print(rnd_search_cv.best_score_)
```

Error

ValueError: Invalid parameter n_neurons for estimator KerasRegressor.
This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasRegressor constructor:
`KerasRegressor(n_neurons=47)`
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`